# How redirect to a sign in page when the user is not authenticated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want a add in action 'destroy' if/else than user was not logged, his redirect to signin page, but I'm doing wrong.

```
def destroy
    if user.sign_in
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
    else
      redirect_to signin_path
    end
  end
```

helper sessions_helper

```
  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end
```

how fix it?
sorry for my bad English

Comment: What's `user.sign_in` ?? can you show `sign_in` method?

Comment: from sessions_helper, update the message

Answer (score 0):

In the destroy method you call to `user.sign_in` but in you helper you have this definition `sign_in(user)` you have to fix that using:

`user.sign_in`

And creating a method on class User

OR:

`sign_in(user)`

Passing user as a param with actual method defined.

**EDITED**

```
ApplicationController

def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
 end

end
```

Comment: I tried now rename 'sign_in' to 'user.sign_in(user)' but it does not work.show error 'undefined local variable or method'

Comment: Put the method on ApplicationController

Comment: pabliiitoo how put?full method copy to ApplicationController (def/body-method/end)?